# Como acessar o valor de um array através da chave?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte array:

```
var arr = [
  {'David': '1'},
  {'Camilla': '2'},
  {'Sadat': '3'},
  {'Vanuza': '4'}, 
  {'Diego': '5'}
];
```

Queria acessar o valor "Camilla" do array que criei. 
Ps: quero acessar o valor da chave e não o índice.

Comment: Você quer, para cada elemento do array, acessar a chave? Ou é para um elemento específico? Esses elementos só tem um par chave/valor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode iterar sobre as chaves de um objeto usando o `for..in`:

```js
var arr = [
  {'David': '1'},
  {'Camilla': '2'},
  {'Sadat': '3'},
  {'Vanuza': '4'}, 
  {'Diego': '5'}
];

arr.forEach(function(objeto) {
  for ( var chave in objeto )
      document.body.innerHTML += "Chave: " + chave + "; Valor: " + objeto[chave] + "<br>";
});
```

Se seu objeto só tem uma chave, esse loop só executará uma vez, então o valor que você quer estará na variável `chave`.

No entanto, eu não recomendaria representar os dados desse jeito, a menos que você tenha um motivo muito bom para tal, pois além da forma de acessar ser inconveniente ainda torna mais difícil estender os objetos no futuro (vai que você precisa colocar mais propriedades). Porque não usar algo mais estruturado?

```
var arr = [
  {nome:'David', valor: '1'},
  {nome:'Camilla', valor: '2'},
  {nome:'Sadat', valor: '3'},
  {nome:'Vanuza', valor: '4'}, 
  {nome:'Diego', valor: '5'}
];
```

Comment: Boa............

Answer (score 2):

Se os objetos estão dentro de um array `var ArrayValues ​​= [ { objeto }, { } objeto , ...] ;` O seguinte assessores da matriz regular funcionará:

> var ValorDavid = arr[0].David.toString();
>
> var ValorCamilla = arr[1].Camilla.toString();

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <title></title>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <script>
        function clica() {
          var arr = [
          { 'David': '1' },
          { 'Camilla': '2' },
          { 'Sadat': '3' },
          { 'Vanuza': '4' },
          { 'Diego': '5' }
          ];
    
          var ValorDavid = arr[0].David.toString();
          var ValorCamilla = arr[1].Camilla.toString();
        }
      </script>
    
    
    
    </head>
    <body>
    
      <input type=button onClick="clica();" value="Testa">
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Seguindo a idéia do @Gabriel Katamura, temos como criar esta função:

```
function getArrValue(arr, m) {
  var filteredArr = arr.find(function(v){ return (m in v); });
  return (!!filteredArr) ? filteredArr[m] : null;
}
```

Depois usar assim `getArrValue(arr, 'Camilla')` ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
arr.find(function(element) {
  return element.hasOwnProperty('Camilla') 
})['Camilla'];
```

Comment: Desculpe, editei o título da pergunta para você entender melhor Gabriel

Answer (score 1):

Qual o contexto em que está utilizando esse array?

Talvez o problema não esteja em como recuperar os valores, mas sim na estrutura de dados que está construindo.

A sua estrutura de dados precisa ser planejada para evitar futuros problemas.

Recomendo utilizar uma estrutura mais genérica, exemplo:

```
var arr = [
 { name: 'David', id: '1'},
 { name: 'Camilla', id: '2'},
 { name: 'Sadat', id: '3'},
 { name: 'Vanuza', id: '4'}, 
 { name: 'Diego', id: '5'}
];
```

Dessa forma conseguirá iterar melhor com sua matriz de dados quando necessitar. Nesse caso por exemplo poderia utilizar uma biblioteca de utilitários como o [lodash](https://lodash.com/) (método `_.find`) que possui vários métodos que te ajuda a manipular dados.

---

EDITADO:

Se ainda preferir deixar a estrutura de dados da forma que está ou não puder muda-la, é possível criar uma função para acessar o valor:

```
function getValueByKey (collection, key) {
  var value;

  collection.map(function (item) {
    if (key in item) value = item[key];
  })

  return value;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t0kt8vkn/

Answer (score -3):

```js
var arr = [
    {'David': '1'},
    {'Camilla': '2'},
    {'Sadat': '3'},
    {'Vanuza': '4'}, 
    {'Diego': '5'}
  ];
 // utilizando o método filter:
 
  var arr2 = arr.filter ( valor => valor.Camilla);
  console.log (arr2);
```